# How to test a website for performance testing having google oauth login?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, testing, google-oauth, performance-testing

I have a website and I need to test it with 250 users. However, I am using google login via OAuth2. The website is hosted on Google App Engine.

I am stuck at this login part.  After we log in we get and access token from Google that is passed to Google APIs via the `Authorization: Bearer` header. We use the access token in the application to get user details and access other google apps for that user. I don't know how to get that access token using my external script.

Comment: can you add a bit more about how your app is structured (eg. server vs. js), and whether you need 250 discrete accounts or 250 sessions of a single account? I use a couple of different approaches. For unit tests I login, grab the current access token, then paste that into my test scripts. For e2e tests I keystroke the login username/password. Also be aware that many (all?) Google APIs are rate limited, so your throughput will be constrained by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to mock / stub this part of your application out during testing. For instance, you can provide a certain header that tells your application that you're in test mode and instead of calling the real google APIs, it calls a mock API instead. If your application is setup for dependency injection this could be trivial, otherwise, it may involve monkey-patching or similar.

Another option is to use an [OAuth2 Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and acquire access tokens for a bunch of users in a test Google Apps domain. Your test script can do this and then just pass the access tokens just as a client normally would.